# Can we write user define functions in azure pipeline yaml file?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

Can we write user define functions in azure pipeline yaml file ?

That means I want to perform a specific task by using a function in any language like (PYTHON,SHELL,PERL etc), which should return the value after the execution of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using [Command Line Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

```
- script: # script path or inline
  workingDirectory: #
  displayName: #
  failOnStderr: #
  env: { string: string } # mapping of environment variables to add
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to do this through CMD task. 

Lets suppose you have written your function and stored it in some library and you want to call your function in some other tasks 

for example I have function1 written in some file and I want to call it as a task 

function1 () {
return 1 ;
}



- FUNCTION: # FILE_NAME
  workingDirectory: #
  displayName: #
  failOnStderr: #
 function parameter: #

Comment: @ParminderSingh why? You can use this to run whatever you want

Comment: can you please help me out with the above example ?

Comment: @ParminderSingh edit your question with the additional information, it'll be easier to read

Answer (score -3):

@Geoffroy

Actually I don't want to do this through CMD task.

Lets suppose I have written one function and stored it in some library and I want to call that function as a Azure tasks.

for example:

I have "function1" written in some file like :

```
function1 (x y) {
    return 1 ; 
}
```

and I want to call function1 as a "Azure task"